# How do I call a function from a variable in a class generated with Reflection.Emit?

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I'm creating a dynamic type with this:

```
AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName("LunarDynamicAssembly");
AssemblyBuilder _assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
ModuleBuilder _moduleBuilder = _assembly.DefineDynamicModule("DynamicModule", true);

TypeBuilder typeBuilder = _moduleBuilder.DefineType(original.Name + "Proxy", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class, original, new Type[] { typeof(IProxy) });

// - This function only implements the IProxy interface and returns the private variable field.
FieldBuilder _interceptor = ImplementIProxy(typeBuilder);
ConstructorInfo _interceptorConstructor = typeof(Interceptor).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);

foreach (ConstructorInfo constructorInfo in original.GetConstructors())
{
    //Omitting for brev.
    //Recreating all the constructors and ensuring there's a line
    //_interceptor = new Interceptor();
    //in all of them.
}

foreach (PropertyInfo pInfo in original.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    MethodInfo getMethod = pInfo.GetGetMethod();
    MethodInfo setMethod = pInfo.GetSetMethod();

    PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(pInfo.Name, pInfo.Attributes, pInfo.PropertyType, null);

    MethodAttributes attributes = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.Final | MethodAttributes.NewSlot;
    MethodBuilder getBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(getMethod.Name, attributes, pInfo.PropertyType, null);
    ILGenerator getIL = getBuilder.GetILGenerator();

    // - Issues start here
    getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, _interceptor);
    getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(Interceptor).GetMethod("InterceptingFunction"));
    getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
    getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);

    getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(getBuilder, getMethod);
}
```

`InterceptingFunction` returns the same type as the property. I'm guessing I'm missing how to put the "instance" part before I call the function, from what I've checked in ILDasm. How can I do this?

Exception: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

**(Edit) More Info** The IL Code of a function that does what I'm trying to generate (except for the return 20 part):

```
// Code size       20 (0x14)
.maxstack  1
.locals init ([0] int32 CS$1$0000)
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldarg.0
IL_0002:  ldfld      class [Test]Test.DataAccess.Interceptor Tests.MyClass::_interceptor
IL_0007:  callvirt   instance void [Test]Test.DataAccess.Interceptor::InterceptingFunction()
IL_000c:  nop
IL_000d:  ldc.i4.s   20
IL_000f:  stloc.0
IL_0010:  br.s       IL_0012
IL_0012:  ldloc.0
IL_0013:  ret
```

Comment: put your code in try catch and check the exception stack trace.

Comment: @gp. It is, there's no InnerException and the stack trace shows `at MyClassProxy.get_ClassID() at Tests.Program.Main(String[] args) in e:\Projects\Tests\Program.cs:line 19`

Comment: the IL code shows InterceptFunction return type is void. I tried a similar sample and "instace" part before function call is not a problem. Check the InterceptFunction signature. Save your dynamic assembly then verify using `peverify`

Answer (score 1):

Constrast

```
getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, _interceptor);
```

with

```
ldfld      class [Test]Test.DataAccess.Interceptor Tests.MyClass::_interceptor
```

The `ldloc` instruction is for *loading locals*, to *load a field*, you need to use `ldfld`.

You also didn't [declare any local variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1xffef4), yet you're trying to use one anyway (`stloc.0`, `ldloc.0`). Though in your case, that local variable is completely unnecessary, you can just leave the value returned from `InterceptingFunction` on the stack. (The working IL does that to help debugging, I belive those extra instructions, along with the unnecessary branch won't be there in Release mode.)